# Re-sizeable UITableViewCell : toggling UITextView in UITableViewCell by using auto layouts

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I had created this.

[image].

please ignore the blur part which is the problem of creating .gif.

I did this using **autolayouts**.

my code is :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

for *toggling* action of *Remarks* button which is written in custom cell class:

```
@IBAction func toggleAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if(hc.constant == 75){
        hc.constant = 0
    }
    else{
        hc.constant = 75
    }

}
```

where **hc** is height constraint of *textview*. What my doubt is that can the tableviewcell will re-size after toggling the below textview? **If yes, How?**

All suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Implement sizeForRowAtIndexpath

Comment: when i click on the button, uitextview will disappear. how the control moves from toggleAction to sizeForRowAtIndexPath @Vakas

Answer (score 0):

After changing constant you have to call either `cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` if change before return cell or `tableView.beginUpdate()` follow up by `tableView.endUpdate()` to update the table view height

You already using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` so it should be update automatically with the constraint

Comment: size is not updating but the remarks button is moving a bit downwards @Tj3n

Comment: have you tried `tableView.beginUpdate()` and `endUpdate` after change `hc.constant`?

Comment: No. this is action written in tableview cell's custom class. I dont have access of table view in that class. @Tj3n

Comment: call delegate to view controller class to tell it to update the cell, only tableview can update the height of the cell

Comment: if you have a clear cut on what to do, can you please provide me working solution ? please @Tj3n

Comment: The easiest way i can offer you if you arent familiar with delegate is you create a `var parentTableView: UITableView` in your cell class, then in `cellForRow`, you can set `cell.parentTableView = tableView`, and you can call it in the action function